# How do I partition my volume group?

Tags: partitioning, disk

I installed ubuntu on a server and I want to reclaim 6TB of space form sda3. How can I mount it so that it is visible in df -h command? Also, where do I get knowledge about these stuff?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used vgcreate to create new partition. Then used ext4 to partition. them mounted the volume.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use fdisk. `fdisk -l` shows disks, and use `fdisk /path/to/disk` to select the disk and enter the menu.  Press `n` to create a new partition. Select the partition type from the menu,  then press `w` to write the changes to fstab.

Then try mounting the partition with `mount /path/to/partition /path/to/mount`